# MariaDB: How can I grant read-only privileges for Stored Procedures?

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, permissions

I've granted SELECT privileges for a user to select on all tables of a database. However that user is unsable to view store procedures.
I'd want to grant only the permission for `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` (or something alike).
Is that possible on MariaDB 10.x?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-procedure/), `SELECT` privileges on `mysql.proc` is sufficient.

Comment: This would mean the user is able to see all Procedures on the MariaDB-Server.
Its not limited to a database.